# How to check which gcloud project is active

Tags: gcloud

To see all your gcloud projects you use command `gcloud projects list`. To switch to a specific project, you use `gcloud config set project PROJECT_ID`.

**But what command can you use when you want to check which project is active?** By which I mean, on which project was called the set command last?

Comment: I think the simplest answer is probably `gcloud config list`

Answer (score 65, accepted):

```sh
gcloud config get-value project
```

You can always type `gcloud config --help`

There's a very cool and well-hidden interactive tool: `gcloud beta interactive` that will help with `gcloud` command completion.

Personally, I recommend not using configurations to hold default values (for e.g. `project`) in order to (help) avoid "To which project did I just apply that command?" issues.

IMO, it's much better to be more explicit and I prefer:

```sh
gcloud ... --project=${PROJECT}
```

If, like me, you put the project value in a variable, you can still make mistakes **but** it is easier to avoid them.

You can also define sets of configurations and then use `gcloud ... --configuration=${CONFIG}` and this works too as long as you don't set values in the `default` config

Comment: You mean like gcloud firestore export gs://BUCKET_NAME --project=MY_PROJECT? Where would I store a variable in console please? Do you have some links for further reading please?

Comment: Assuming you're using Linux, you can e.g. `PROJECT="some-project-id"` and then `gcloud projects describe ${PROJECT}` and e.g.  `gcloud compute images list --project=${PROJECT}`

Comment: I'm not using linux. I'll try to research it, thank you.

Comment: You could also use `gcloud config get project`

Comment: Response I get for `gcloud config get-value project` is `Your active configuration is: [cloudshell-4082]` which does not correspond to any project ID, Name or Number  ... ?

Comment: @James -- you're running the command on [Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell) and the this creates a `gcloud` [configuration](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/configurations) unique to the Cloud Shell instance (`cloudshell-xxxx` you can see this using `gcloud config configurations list`). The following line was likely `(unset)` which refers to the fact that you don't have a default Project set for the configuration being used in Cloud Shell. If you have a specific question, please consider asking it as a new question.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can use `gcloud projects list --filter='lifecycleState:ACTIVE'` to get all active projects.
2. Or you can list them all showing `lifecyclestate` and filter with grep or other bash stuff:

```bash
$ gcloud projects list --format="table(projectNumber,projectId,createTime.date(tz=LOCAL),lifecycleState)" --limit 10
PROJECT_NUMBER  PROJECT_ID                 CREATE_TIME          LIFECYCLE_STATE
310270846648    again-testing-no-notebook  2022-12-11T07:03:03  ACTIVE
[...]
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

`gcloud info` will give the project.